# free backup utility supporting usb plug notification

Tags: backup, usb, notifications

Is there any free backup utility which is able to start automatically (without any confirmation) the backup to a usb external disk when I plug it? No windows native autorun.inf feature, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Backup maker](http://www.ascomp.de/index.php?php=prog&page=func&prog=backupmaker) supposedly does this, haven't tried it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

[Backup SafeKeeper](http://www.speedapps.com/safekeeper.htm) has a "Set it and forget it" option, but the only way to find out what this means is to try it.

An excellent commercial product that does it for sure is [SyncBackSE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse.html). I mention it although it's not free because I use it a lot (but alas, the free version).